# Unity3d Facebook mobile SDK test in Unity Editor?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I was wondering if unity3d facebook sdk can be tested within the unity editor itself.

Right now, for every change i make i have to deploy on the device and this is painstakingly slow for debugging. It would be great if i can do the same inside the editor.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's limited functionality of the SDK being able to be tested in the editor.  There are fake dialogs that will pop up and won't do anything.  The `FB.API()` within the Editor requires a parameter `access_token`.  So there's a limited amount of stuff that can be done within the Editor.  It's on our todo list to make it so more things work within the Editor.

Comment: Thanks Brian, i hope sooner or later that is possible. For now, i guess, device is the only way.